# Is possible to edit/change/delete a published comment in Gerrit?

Tags: gerrit

I have added a comment in Gerrit and I have published it. I would like to edit it after publishing. Is that possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, [Gerrit does not support editing comments](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=4445) that have been published. You can edit (or discard) them before publishing, whey they're in the "Draft" status.

However, if you desperately need to do it, you must have access to the Gerrit's database. You can find comments (and do whatever you want to with them) in the `patch_comments` table.

---

**31.05.2018**:
Since Gerrit v2.15, published comments' text [can be deleted by Gerrit's administrators](https://www.gerritcodereview.com/releases/2.15.md#delete-inline-comments). This does not delete the whole comment, but its contents only.

There is more info in [the delete endpoint docs](https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.15/rest-api-changes.html#delete-comment):

> Instead of deleting the whole comment, [it] just replaces the comment’s message with a new message, which contains the name of the user who deletes the comment and the reason why it’s deleted. [...] Note that only users with the Administrate Server global capability are permitted to delete a comment.

This feature is available only in the new PolyGerrit UI.

Comment: This seems like a serious design limitation because it means that it would be extremely easy to perform a nasty DDOS attack on any public gerrit server: write a bot that adds a comment with some copyrighted or private information content and after this send a takedown notice.